# How can I use auth for custom guard in my package using laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to make auth through laravel package using `admins` table. In the project directory I added `admin` guard into config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

And in the guard array

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

Following is my login controller inside pacakge

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

   use AuthenticatesUsers;
   protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';
   protected function redirectTo()
   {
         return '/admin/dashboard';
   }

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
   }
   public function login(Request $request)
   {   
       if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password'), true)){
           return redirect()
               ->intended(route('dashboard'))
               ->with('status','You are Logged in as Admin!');
       }
   }

}
```

and following is my dashboard controller

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        /* dd(Auth::check()); */ //return false : just want to show you

          $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('xyz::dashboard');
    }

}
```

And in my `Admin.php` Model following script is there

```
namespace App;

class Admin extends \ABC\xyz\App\Models\Admin
{

}
```

Which is extending package model

```
namespace ABC\xyz\App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'admins';
}
```

And below are the routes from my package

```
    $namespace = 'ABC\Xyz\App\Http\Controllers';
    Route::group([    
    'namespace' => $namespace,
    'middleware' => ['web'], 
    'prefix' => 'admin'
], function () {
    Route::get('login', function(){
        return view('xyz::auth.login');
    })->name('login');

    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('customLogin');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

When I try to login, after submitting valid details it does not redirecting me to dashboard, nothing happening. Also when I try for open forcefully /dashboard it take me to login page.

Also right after login attempt when I try `Auth::check()` it's returns `true` but same thing returning `false` in `dashboardController.php` construct function. In the same way `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` returns user's info while on `dashboardController.php` it's returns `null`. I don't know what and where I am missing something.

I would like to request you kindly guide me about it.  I would appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: Don't you need to register middleware group in `app\Http\kernel.php` ? same as web?

Comment: @danish-khan-I I don't think so

Comment: What does `Auth::user()` return. It is returning an `Admin` instance? Also important note in developing a package: keep config of guards, providers or other things inside the package but changable by the developer. Also use names that relate to your package `mypackage_admin`. The developer might already have an `admin` guard configured.

Comment: What about your AuthServiceProvider, did you register the guard?

Answer (score 0):

When you define a route with a Prefix, the route name will be like `prefix.name` and the url will be like `prefix/url`. So here you can try this

```
Route::group([    
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'middleware' => ['web'], 
        'prefix' => 'admin'
    ], function () {
        Route::get('login', function(){
            return view('xyz::auth.login');
        })->name('login');

        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('tryForLogin');
});

Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', function(){
        return view('xyz::dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

All group was prefixed by "admin" , but there are some route or page that can be visited when its logged in.

Comment: it is giving me an error that is `Route [admin.dashboard] not defined.
`

Comment: I see it now, its because you put another group that take auth inside web middleware. I'll edit the answer and you can try my method.

Comment: it does not working, again returning to dashboard route

Comment: After every changes on your routes use `php artisan optimize`. To check if you have your route defined use `php artisan route:list`. It may have a wrong definition name.

Answer (score 0):

The `prefix` are an option for defining a prefix the routes endpoint. You are looking for the `as` option.

```
// gives you routes:
// GET /admin/login named "admin.login" with middleware "web"
// POST /admin/login named "admin.tryForLogin" with middleware "web"
Route::group([    
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'middleware' => ['web'], 
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'as' => 'admin.'
    ], function () {
        Route::get('login', function() {
            return view('xyz::auth.login');
        })
        ->name('login');

        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('tryForLogin');
    }
);

// gives you routes:
// GET /admin/dashboard named "admin.dashboard" with middleware "auth"
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', function(){
        return view('xyz::dashboard');
    })
    ->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Run `php artisan optimize:clear` after code changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `guest` middleware (`\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`) is responsible for redirecting authenticated users.

When using the middleware, you have to pass it the authentication guard to be used like this:

`guest:guard`

Example: in your LoginController constructor, use

`$this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');`

instead of `$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');`

Answer (score 0):

use `auth('admin')->user()` in your dashboard controller. (returns authenticated admin)

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more for the newbies that might come across it.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin Model class needs to extend the User Model Class. That way, the Admin Model class will inherit the Authenticable Class.

The Authenticable Class is responsible for the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To use authentication for a custom guard in your package using Laravel 6, you will need to define your custom guard in the `config/auth.php` file. Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Define your custom guard in the `guards` array of the `config/auth.php` file:

```php
'guards' => [
    'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'custom',
    ],
],
```

In this example, we have defined a guard named `custom` which uses the `session` driver and the `custom` provider.

2. Define your custom provider in the `providers` array of the `config/auth.php` file:

```php
'providers' => [
    'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\CustomUser::class,
    ],
],
```

In this example, we have defined a provider named `custom` which uses the `eloquent` driver and the `App\CustomUser` model.

3. Implement the `Authenticatable` interface on your custom user model (`App\CustomUser` in this example) and define the necessary methods (such as `getAuthIdentifier()` and `getAuthPassword()`).
4. Use the `auth()->guard('custom')->attempt()` method to authenticate a user for the `custom` guard. For example:

```php
if (auth()->guard('custom')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
}
```

In this example, we are attempting to authenticate a user using the `email` and `password` fields. If authentication is successful, the code inside the `if` statement will be executed.

5. You can also use the `auth()->guard('custom')->check()` method to check if the user is currently authenticated for the `custom` guard.

```php
if (auth()->guard('custom')->check()) {
    // User is authenticated...
}
```

These are the basic steps to use authentication for a custom guard in your package using Laravel 6. You may need to modify these steps based on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You will add the **auth:guard** to the **route middleware**.

Change

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

to

```
Route::group(['namespace' => $namespace,'prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => ['auth:admin']  ], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this method**
*I have used it before and it works*

**1. Open config/auth.php**

Add `'admin' => ['driver' => 'session','provider' => 'admin',],`
To guards

Then add `'admin' => ['driver' => 'eloquent','model' => App\Admin::class,],` To providers

Also `'admin' => ['provider' => 'admin','table' => 'password_resets','expire' => 60,],` For passwords

**2. Open app/Http/Middleware**

Then create AdminMiddleware.php in there (inside middleware folder)

*Copy and paste below code in AdminMiddleware.php page*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware{ 
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard='admin')

{

  if (!auth()->guard($guard)->check()) {
    //If admin is not authenticated the redirect to admin login page
    return redirect('/admin/login'); // it depends on how to have or set 
     // your route for admin login page
  }
    return $next($request);
} 
}
```

**3. Open app/Http/Kernel.php page**

Add

```
use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware; //from the middleware //Along 
    //with other use;
```

Then add

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
 ] // protected already exists you only need to add 'admin' => 
    // AdminMiddleware::class,
```

**4. In your admin controllers**

Add

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin'); 
}
```

Just the way we have below for users or auth

```
 public function __construct()
   {
   $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

**5. Admin Model would be the same with User model just that the class namw would be diff i.e Admin**

**6 Admin route would be like this**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

// Login Routes...
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'AdminAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);

Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'AdminAuth\LoginController@login']);

Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'admin.logout', 'uses' => 'AdminAuth\LoginController@logout']);


// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'admin.password.request', 'uses' => 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);


Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'admin.password.email', 'uses' => 'AdminAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);


Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'admin.password.reset', 'uses' => 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);


Route::post('password/reset', ['uses' => 'AdminAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);


//Dashboard
Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 'AdminDashboardController@index']);
});
```

**7 Admin Login Controller**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminAuth;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

  class LoginController extends Controller
   {
  /*
|----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  ---
| Login Controller
|----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 ---
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

 use AuthenticatesUsers;

  /**
  * Where to redirect users after login.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';

  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   // public function __construct()
  // {
  //     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  // }

   protected function guard()
  {

    return auth()->guard('admin');
    }

  public function showLoginForm()
   {

    return view('AdminAuth.login');
    }



  public function logout(Request $request)
  {
   auth()->guard('admin')->logout();

   $request->session()->invalidate();

   return redirect('admin/login');
 }
```

}

*Note that just the way we have Auth folder in Controller folder, we would also need AdminAuth the you would create the Login controller in there*